# parallel has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, associations, has-many-through, has-many

I have the following models:

```rb
class Account
  has_many :credits, class_name: "Charge", inverse_of: :dst, foreign_key: :dst_id
  has_many :debits, class_name: "Charge", inverse_of: :src, foreign_key: :src_id
  has_many :occurrences, through: [:credits, :debits] # not sure about this
end

class Charge 
  belongs_to :src, class_name: "Account", foreign_key: :src_id, inverse_of: :debits
  belongs_to :dst, class_name: "Account", foreign_key: :dst_id, inverse_of: :credits
  has_many :occurrences
end

class Occurrences
  belongs_to: :charge
end
```

This situation is similar to the classic Twitter follower/followed example.

What I'm trying to model is a charge that takes money from one account and deposits it into another.

How can I access from `Account` all occurrences through `debits` and `credits`?